# Supercapacitor voltage rating vs supply

Tags: supercapacitor

I have a PowerStor Aerogel 5V 1.0F PB SERIES capacitor.

The datasheet specifies a max voltage of 5V and a surge voltage of 6V.

I understand I can safely use this capacitor in a 3.3V system. Will it also work in a 5V system or is it dangerous to run it like that?

Comment: what's the expected life of board with super capacitor. actual charging voltage will depend on life expectancy.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a rule of thumb for low voltage capacitors is 20% tolerance minimum. That being said, if this is a non inductive circuit for example the output from a 5V LDO powering a low power embedded system and the capacitor has a surge voltage rating of 6V, I would say it would be alright.

Also note: the datasheet lists "5V" as a feature, this could point to them expecting use in 5V circuits.

Just make sure you are not coming close to any other specs such as current draw, temperature range etc that could cause additional stress.

Also take note of specifications like leakage current, my guess is at its maximum voltage this will start creeping up a lot.

Comment: Yeah the datasheet isn't very clear. I also thought they expect one to use this in 5V systems. I got this capacitor many years ago, back when 5V microcontrollers were common.